# Regarding flash the code on to the ESP32 board

Tags: c

Command to flash the code on ESP32 the command is shown in below.The command is used in Linux OS.

```
./vendors/espressif/esp-idf/tools/idf.py erase_flash flash monitor -p /dev/ttyUSB0 -B builde
```

Here `builde` is a project directory.

The output of this command shown below.
It will give me a error related to the `-B` option.

```
Usage: ./vendors/espressif/esp-idf/tools/idf.py monitor [OPTIONS]
Try './vendors/espressif/esp-idf/tools/idf.py monitor --help' for help.

Error: Invalid value for '--monitor-baud' / '-B': builde is not a valid integer
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: When i flash the code in to ESP32 board , Using this command i get this error , Means -B option is not valid... How to solve this , Please anyone help me about this?

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear, Have a look here => [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I think you need to put all the options (-*) before all the commands.

Why do you want to change the build directory, btw?
Usually to flash and build an IDF application, you would use:
`idf.py build flash monitor`. You don't need to erase normally.

Answer (score 0):

-b is optional but requires the baud rate so something like -b 921600